# How do I define a Route with multiple different paths?

Tags: 8, routes, path-aliases

Does Drupal's routing system support a regular expression or other means for multiple route paths? I have a route that I would like to be able to hit from two different endpoints, `/api/v1/foo` and `/api/v1/foo_bar`. One route is newer, the other I want to keep for backwards compatibility reasons.

In my module's `my_module.routing.yml` file, I have defined:

```
foo:
  path: 'api/v1/foo'
  defaults: { _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyController::doItAction' }
  methods:  [GET]
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'

foo_bar:
  path: 'api/v1/foo_bar'
  defaults: { _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyController::doItAction' }
  methods:  [GET]
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

This works, but as you can see everything after the route name and `path` property is copy/pasted. It's not exactly adhering to the DRY principle. Now this is a simple case, but imagine if I had a much more involved route with complex requirements and parameters. There would be a very high chance of making a typo or pasting mistake in one.

Is it possible to define the `path` as a regular expression or something similar so I don't have to repeat all the route properties?

Comment: You can't use regular expressions, but to avoid to repeat the route properties you can define the routes dynamically, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/providing-dynamic-routes

Answer (score 3):

```
cool:
  path: 'api/v1/{dynamic}'
  defaults: { _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyController::doItAction' }
  methods:  [GET]
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

Then in your controller

```
public function doItAction($dynamic) {

  if($dynamic == 'foo' || $dynamic == 'foo_bar') {
    // your code
  } 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem with this is that I have many paths of the form `api/v1/{dynamic}` (besides the ones above, that map to different controllers), meaning they would all get captured by this one route rule. That would bloat the Controller action with a bunch of checking logic and sort of defeat the purpose of having a routing file.